# Editing Chart Information in Word Documents using Python docx package

Tags: python, excel, ms-word

I am trying to automate the charts present in a Word Document. However, I am unsure on how to access the chart information to do so. Currently I have tried to use the docx package to access the Inline Objects that are present in the Word Document. However, I am unable to find the feature element that is responsible for creating the embeded charts in the Words Documen. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Would this be of use: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/charts.html

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I believe this would have worked if I am adding a graph, but currently I am trying to find a way to access the embeded excel files that are present in the word documents that creates the individual charts. If anyone has information on how to access that, that will be great! Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Clarence Ong, Welcome to SOF. It would be great, if you could please add more details regarding what is the research you have done from your end to implement the same. Thanks!